# Azure Web App HTTP/HTTPS rewrite rules

Tags: azure, redirect, iis, web-config, http-redirect

I have an angular app that I host in a Microsoft Azure Web Site. I've set it up with auto-redirect of all requests to HTTPS by installing an extension for me: https://github.com/gregjhogan/redirect-http-to-https-site-extension

What the extension app does is that it adds an applicationhost.xdt file which looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location path="%XDT_SITENAME%" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(path)">
    <system.webServer xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <rewrite xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <rules xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" lockElements="clear">
          <rule name="redirect HTTP to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true" lockItem="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
              <add input="{WARMUP_REQUEST}" pattern="1" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Now that works fine, and everything is redirected to HTTPS. Now I've come across a new requirement, and I want to edit the rewrite rule to the following: Redirect all requests to HTTPS (as it is now), except any url that contains the following: "/#/user/[Some random user id]".

I've read different posts, and tried some different stuff, but IIS setup and stuff like this isn't quite my domain, and I'm strugling finding it out. The try I feel like is close is when I added this {REQUEST_URI} condition:

```html
<conditions>
  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
  <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern=".*/#/user/.+" ignoreCase="true" />
  <add input="{WARMUP_REQUEST}" pattern="1" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```

I've tried restarting the Azure Web App, as well as redeploying it, but it doesn't seem kick in, everything still redirects to HTTPS as the original rule applies.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing your regex online, and it seems that you need to escape the forward slash:

```
\/#\/user\/.+
```

Tested string:

```
http://localhost/#/user/123
```

Tested regex:

```
\/#\/user\/.+
```

website:
http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately it didnt work.. Im having trouble debugging it. Any idea how to debug?

Comment: debugging the regex? Through this regextester.com is not helpful?

Comment: Yes, that was helpful. What I meant is that when I can say that the regex is correct, but I still don't get the redirect as I want. How do I debug the actual redirect on the server? Is that even possible?

Comment: you could automate your tests using a UI automation framework such as Selenium or Coded UI. I think it's the easier way. Also, you can use the URL Rewrite Module on IIS and test trough that. http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/testing-rewrite-rule-patterns

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  this to your  Application_beginrequest  event

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection && !HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.Contains("/#/user/[Some random user id]"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]
                                         + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
        }
```